# XML error Open quote is expected for attribute "value" when programming in PHP

Tags: php, xml, zoho

Hello and thank you for your help,

I am using PHP to write an XML request, the problem I am having is when I use the variable in the value field, it returns an error. However when I write in the value manually it works perfectly. 
Under field name='Serial_Number' you will see the $MREPSerial is the variable, let's assume that 
in the PHP we have $MREPSerial = 'A-000-1042'; The below XML would give an error. However if i were to replace $MREPSerial with just the value in the XML it would be successful. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
$MREPSerial  = htmlspecialchars(strtoupper($_POST['NSMREP']));
echo "Hi".$MREPSerial;
<ZohoCreator>
            <applicationlist>
                <application name='ajout-de-materiel'>
                    <formlist>
                        <form name='MREP'>
                            <update>
                                <criteria>
                                    <field name='Serial_Number' compOperator='Equals' value={$MREPSerial}></field>
                                    <reloperator>AND</reloperator>
                                    <field name='MREP_Type' compOperator='Equals' value='0'></field>                            
                                </criteria>
                                <newvalues>
                                    <field name='Is_being_Used' value='TRUE'></field>
                                </newvalues>
                            </update>    
                        </form>
                    </formlist>
                </application>
            </applicationlist>
        </ZohoCreator>";
```

...
the return response on echo (including the XML i echoed)

```
A-000-1012HI! <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response><errorlist><error><code>2830</code><message><![CDATA[Open quote is expected for attribute "value" associated with an  element type  "field".]]></message></error></errorlist></response>
```

the return response on echo if i change it to '".$MREPSerial." is:

```
A-000-1012HI! <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response><result><form name="MREP"><update><criteria><field name="Serial_Number" compOperator="Equals" value=""></field><reloperator>AND</reloperator><field name="MREP_Type" compOperator="Equals" value="0"></field></criteria><newvalues><field name="Is_being_Used"><value><![CDATA[TRUE]]></value></field></newvalues> <status>Failure, No Records Found With Specified Criteria</status></update></form></result></response>
```

Comment: how are you jumping in and out of PHP?  `...compOperator='Equals' value='<?PHP echo $MREPSerial; ?>'>...`

Comment: Sorry this is all in PHP I just didn't add the entire PHP page, the XML is a variable $param = "XMLString=
   <ZohoCreator> ....

Comment: can you do the following for me;   `echo '[['.$MREPSerial.']]';`  and show the output again...

Comment: on echo this is what is returned [[A-000-1012]] (the 1012 is because I changed the number, but should work)

Comment: no clue... doesn't make sense.  Perhaps post a wider section of code before/after including where you assign and test output the $MREPSerial...  perhaps it is something else.

Comment: Thanks Dave, you were right it was something somewhat stupid. Since my XML is called in a function and my variable is called outside the function, I was not getting the value. I had to make it global.

Answer (score 3):

You need quotes around the value attribute's actual value, like this:

```
<field name='Serial_Number' compOperator='Equals' value='{$MREPSerial}'></field>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, unfortunatley I tried that and I received the XML message instead of FALSE value does not exist, and that is because the XML shows the value as blank (shown below)  <field name="Serial_Number" compOperator="Equals" value="">

Comment: are you sure the variable is populated?

Comment: If the value is blank, then the problem is in outputting your variable. Do you need an `echo` or `print` in there.  I wasn't sure how you were using this template, so I didn't comment on that. If empty string are permissible, then perhaps you need to write `'null'` or something else here as placeholder for empty string.

Comment: The value is populate, I have echoed the value and it shows, I will edit the information to show how I did this.

Answer (score 0):

just saw your `";` close tag...

try this for that line

```
 <field name='Serial_Number' compOperator='Equals' value='".$MREPSerial."'></field>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, also gives the same error 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<response><result><form name="MREP"><update><criteria><field name="Serial_Number" compOperator="Equals" value=""></field><reloperator>AND</reloperator><field name="MREP_Type" compOperator="Equals" value="0"></field></criteria><newvalues><field name="Is_being_Used"><value><![CDATA[TRUE]]></value></field></newvalues> <status>Failure, No Records Found With Specified Criteria</status></update></form></result></response>